# Desktop Icon Locations available to Live Wallpapers? (android)

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically retrieve the desktop icons within a WallpaperService ?

Comment: Melodramatically?  I suppose you could play church organ music whilst doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but it's not possible. I asked the same question a few months ago and got this response: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/46a1af6fd9de9bf5